# SQL Where in: better use a static array or a select?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL database where i need to delete some entrys of a table `father`, but there are some FK´s with restrictions between my table `father` and a table `child`, for that, i have to delete from the `child` table and afterwards delete from the `father` table.
There i have:

```
DELETE FROM child WHERE child.id IN (SELECT id FROM father);
```

I would like to know, if it would have a performance change (besides the extra select) if i used

```
DELETE FROM child WHERE child.id IN (1,2,...,n)
```

Where 1,2...n it´s the same result as 'SELECT id FROM father'.

Comment: Probably better to use the referential trigger action `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so that when you delete from the parent the child rows are automatically deleted. But to answer your question a query with the values hard coded is probably going to be faster, since it only has to perform on action, not a lookup and a delete. However, typing out the delete with values is probably going to take longer than you save in execution time by not using a subquery.

Comment: The best way to know the answer to this is to try it yourself and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster than either is to use a multi-table DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM child
    USING father JOIN child 
        ON child.id = father.id;
```

Shouldn't it be `child.father_id`??  No, even that seems wrong??

This seems closer to your English:

```
DELETE FROM child
    USING father JOIN child 
        ON child.father_id = father.id   -- more likely FK
    WHERE father...;   -- picking the Dads in question
DELETE FROM father
    WHERE father...;   -- picking the Dads in question
```

`ON DELETE CASCADE` may be slightly faster.

Comment: Didn´t know about the `USING` parameter. Thanks.